# Reading two lines of integers

Tags: c, scanf

By using [this](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-take-the-input-of-a-line-of-integers-separated-by-a-space-in-C) suggestion I read input like that:

```
10 11 12 13
```

But when I wanted to read two lines input:

```
10 11 12 13
9 8 78 3 12 11 2
```

with code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
  int i=0, j=0, k=0, l=0;
  int arr[10000];
  int brr[10000];
  char temp, temp2;
  do {
      scanf("%d%c", &arr[i], &temp);
      i++;
  } while(temp != '\n');

  do {
      scanf("%d%c", &brr[j], &temp2);
      j++;
  } while(temp2 != '\n');

  for(k=0; k<i; k++) {
    printf("%d ", arr[k]);
  }

  for(l=0; l<j; l++) {
    printf("%d ", brr[l]);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

program has frozen ([example](https://ideone.com/cF5bTh)).

Info from OPs comment:

- first line ends in a newline
- second line ends with EOF

How to read two lines of ints into two different arrays?

Comment: Does the input have a newline after the second line?

Comment: What are  the return value of the calls to `scanf()`?

Comment: @Yunnosch Oh..., You're right. It doesn't. Thank you, so simple mistake.

Comment: @Yunnosch Second line ends with EOF.

Comment: Don't declare arrays of size 10000 on the stack.

Comment: With input like `"123-456"`, `scanf("%d%c", ...` causes problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code assumes a newline after the second input line.
If there is none ... inifinity.

You can extend your loop condition to also stop when `scanf()` does not succeed in reading two parts.